How to pull/checkout only single file in Jenkins pipeline using GitSCM plugin?
I would like to pull only single file inside particular folder from github repo during jenkins pipeline using GitSCM plugin.
Can it done using GitSCM plugin? or only option available for this scenario is to execute git commands inside shell?
Didn't find any solution online for this.

In 'Additional Behaviours', use 'Sparse Checkout paths', This will only checkout the file mentioned in given Path.

If your setup allows it the most convenient way to read a single file without whole repo checkout might be to use the readTrusted step.

readTrusted 'subdir/file' is similar to node {checkout scm; readFile 'subdir/file'}

